"Server Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost failed to start"

I am getting this problem on Particular one Project only.

Remaining Project is working fine without any problem.

I Deleted Server and Removed from Runtime Environment also. And Again added server.

My project is on Admin login, Employee login etc... when I tried Servlet for add employee then it shows this problem. But the Program have no issue.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
